# Windows/Linux child process STDIN differences

Tags: linux, windows, perl, process, stdin

I built a simple text processing script at work to be used by another program. When I was done, someone remembered that the script needs to not block STDIN/STDOUT for the tool using it to work right, and modified the script accordingly. The script opens *nix's `cat` in a subprocess via [`IPC::Open2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open2) and prints STDIN to it, reads it back and then processes and prints it to STDOUT. I have no idea how that makes the script non-blocking, but it apparently worked.

I wanted it to work on Windows as well, so I changed out `cat` for `type CON`, which is a simple Windows command for printing STDIN. A sample script is below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Handle;
use IPC::Open2;

my $command = ($^O eq 'MSWin32') ? 'type CON' : 'cat';

my ( $com_reader, $com_writer ) = ( IO::Handle->new, IO::Handle->new );
open2( $com_reader, $com_writer, $command );
# input
while (<STDIN>) {
    print "first line: $_";
    print $com_writer "$_";
    my $line = <$com_reader>;
    # ...process $line...

    print "next line: $line";
}
```

However the results are completely different. On Windows the STDIN streams for the main script and in the child script seem to be different, while on Linux they are the same. On Windows (I type 1 and 2 on separate lines of input):

```
>perl test.pl
>1
first line: 1
>2
next line: 2
>1
>2
first line: 2
next line: 1
>1
>2
first line: 2
next line: 1
>1
>2
first line: 2
next line: 1
```

On Linux (same input):

```
>perl test.pl
>1
first line: 1
next line: 1
>2
first line: 2
next line: 2
>1
first line: 1
next line: 1
>2
first line: 2
next line: 2
```

Why is the output different, and how can I make the Windows behavior match the Linux behavior? Also, why does this "open cat in subprocess and pipe input through it" trick work at all?

Comment: @Harry Johnston, Two-way interactive communication with a child process.

Comment: @harry Johnston, In practice, it will be a more complex program.

Comment: @Nate: the reason the script as written behaves oddly, by the way, is because the script and the child process are competing for the same input source.

Comment: @Harry Johnston, They're not suppose to be using the same input source. Even if you fixed that, he'll still have problems.

Comment: @ikegami: it really doesn't sound as if `cat` is a stand-in for a more complicated program.  The OP was told that feeding data to `cat` and back "makes the script non-blocking".  I'm fairly sure that's nonsense.

Comment: Nate, my best guess is that piping the data to `cat` and back is completely unnecessary, and all you really needed to do to make the script work is disable buffering by saying `$| = 1` ; if so, that should work on both Linux and Windows.  If `cat` really is doing something magic that fixes a real problem, you're going to need to figure out exactly what the problem is and why `cat` fixes it; we'll need more information to help you with that.  Start by showing us what your original script looked like (before your colleague "fixed" it) and tell us what goes wrong when you use it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Indeed, cat is being used as some magic wand; the surrounding program is more complicated, but cat is used in the real thing. The fix you give makes a lot of sense, and I'm going to try it tomorrow.

Comment: @HarryJohnston actually this puzzles me. What is the practical difference between `print while(<STDIN>)` and `$|++; print while(<STDIN>)`? They both seem to print immediately after retrieving one line, with no buffering suffering.

Comment: @Nate: when you're writing to the console, buffering is automatically disabled, so there's no difference.  It does make a difference when standard output is redirected.  I was assuming that the tool that uses your script redirects your script's standard output, because that seemed the only reasonable guess as to what the original problem was.

Comment: @HarryJohnston It was just buffering. The other stuff was just a (non-working) crazy workaround passed down from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Windows verus Linux thing. You simply picked two awful examples.

1. `type con` reads from the console, not from STDIN. This can be seen using `type con <nul`.
2. `cat` is extremely unusual. Buffering, on either system, is completely up to the individual application, but almost all applications work the same way, and it's different than how `cat` works. `cat` goes out of its way to make this very scenario work.

Replace `cat` with `perl -pe1` to see the behaviour of virtually every other program:

```
1
first line: 1
<deadlock>
```

The way to convince those "normal" programs to line-buffer rather than block-buffer their output is to create a pseudo-tty. This is what Expect and `unbuffer` does, for example. This, of course, won't work in Windows. I'm not sure on what Windows programs base their decision to buffer, but I don't think it can be easily faked because I've never heard of a way to do it.

Comment: Why does `perl -pe1` cause deadlock? Also, `type CON` repeats whatever I type in the cmd, which I assumed was STDIN. What is it reading instead?

Comment: @Nate: CON is the console input, i.e., the keyboard.

Comment: `<$com_reader>` blocks until a newline is received from the child, but `child` won't print anything until it has 4k (Perl's old default) or 8k (Perl's new default) of data to print, which it can only get from its parent, but its parent won't send any more data because it's blocked.